# wildcard of specific length search in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I can't seem to find an answer to this.
I have a small `.dat` file. From that file I would like to extract certain data. As you can see there is a 9 characters long string plus a space then Fixed Value that string is what I would like to find.
One particular line of data is:

```
hEu 5RS67UCJ2 Fixed Value Ü  Ü 5UZZNKV0I Fixed Value Ü3  Ü3 3D910PZ9H Fixed Value Ú9.Ü")  Ú90Ü#- Ü") 5YWX8DMR2 Fixed Value Ü  Ü  54WI4OGWI Fixed Value Ü
```

Comment: You need to tell us what data you want to extract.

Comment: sorry the editor kept wiping out what I typed I thought I could go back and edit it but that didn;t work....sorry for the ugliness

Comment: make a newline at your data, and tab it in w/ 4 spaces

Comment: thanks, everytime I presse dthe space or added anything the whole thing was disappearing.

Comment: for reference: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to match a nine-character uppercase alphanumeric string followed by "Fixed Value" then the following regular expression ought to do the trick:

```
([A-Z0-9]{9}) Fixed Value
```

The parentheses around the first part of the pattern form a capture sub-group, so you should be able to refer to this captured part in a "replace" value by using `$1` or `\1` (depending on how Notepad++ works) in the position where you want the nine-character string to be inserted in the "replace" value.

Comment: Didn't realize np++ added support for the extra syntax. Kudos to you.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!, I was trying to simply do `[0-9A-Z] Fixed Value`